# kendo datasource transport example with a read function that preprocesses data before kendo sees it

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am having a mess of a time getting a server polling application to work with kendo dataSource and kendo grid. Periodically, I must destroy (or empty or clear) the grid's existing datasource and replace it with another one identical in its schema structure but containing different data.

The data are fetched from the server via $http (angular) and the  dataset from the server has to be cleaned up a bit before the grid sees it.

Finally, we won't always know at page-load what data need to be fetched. It will depend on actions/choices the user makes. So the grid has to start out either without a datasource or with a dummy datasource that has the correct schema structure but an empty model.

The problem I'm encountering is that when the newer fresher data are retrieved from the server, and the grid's dataSource data property is given the new array, the UI continues to display the stale data.

Is there an example that shows how this should be done?

P.S. There are about 500 items in the dataset array.  The problems I'm seeing may relate to the size of the dataset.

Comment: When the grid's dataSource fetches the new data the grid should automatically update.  You should be able to just call grid.dataSource.read() repeatedly to see the new data.  Can you post your grid's configuration?

Comment: I do not have the transport set up that way. The data for the grid are fetched when a user chooses an item in another list. I think my problem may be related to using the `ng-delay` feature of kendo for use with angular.